# Unable to cast object of type 'demo.Class1' to type 'demo.Class2'

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

My object cannot be converted into other object please help

it shows the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'demo.Class1' to type 'demo.Class2'.

```
public class Class1
{
    public int a;
    public string b;

    public void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ABC");
    }
}
public class Class2 : Class1
{
    public string d;
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        c.a = 1;
        c.b = "A";

        Class2 c2 = (Class2)c;

    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Why would you think this works? All `Class2` can be cast to `Class1, but not the other way round.

Comment: You should really read up on the base concepts of polymorphism and class inheritance, but to give you a rough idea: e.g. each `Square` is a `Rectangle`, so in OOP you could have `class Square : Rectangle`. And what you're code is trying to do is similar to: I have a rectangle. I now want it to be a square. How?

Answer (score 3):

The Class 2 is a subtype of Class 1. This means you can cast Class2 objects into a Class1 type but not the other way around.

To clarify with less abstract names: Class1 is an Animal and Class2 is a dog. You can say a dog is an animal, but an animal is not always a dog.